# Smoothness of morphisms of deformation functors.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

Under the category of Artin local $k$-algebras $(Art/k)$, let $\alpha: F\to G$ be a morphism of deformation functors. The morphism $\alpha$ is called smooth if for all small extensions $0\to N\to B\to A\to 0$ the canonical map $F(B)\to F(A)\times_{G(A)} G(B)$ is surjective . Now we define a deformation functor $D_{X,p}(A)$={$a\in h_X(\operatorname{Spec}A)|a|_{\operatorname{Spec}(A/m_A)}=p$}, where $h_X=Hom(-,X)$.

Then it’s said that a morphism $f:X\to Y$ of schemes is smooth at a point $p\in X$ such that $f(p)$ has residual field $k$, if and only if the corresponding morphism of functors $D_{X,p}\to D_{Y,f(p)}$ is smooth, by a so called “formal criterion for smoothness.” A smooth morphism is étale iff it’s also an isomorphism of tangent space.

I can’t find any criterion that can indicate this relation explicitly. Hope someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: A typo: your sentence which begins "The morphism $\alpha$ is called smooth ..." is missing a condition at the end of the sentence. Next, what are you looking for an explanation of? Are you looking for the definition of the formal criteria for smoothness, or why it's equivalent to the statement about deformation functors?

Comment: @KReiser- I want them all.